# Community♦ bot editing posting

Tags: support, editing

The question [Recent Linux USB exploits](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4014/665) has been [edited by](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/4014/revisions) Community♦. According to the description on the [user page](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) that is a bot.

The edit is not a organizational one, but adds real content. It's obvious that this cannot be done by a computer program.

Comment: Obligatory: http://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: @Graham - see, THAT kind of CAPTCHA I would get behind! Even if it blocks me once in a while.... :$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated [Community's user page](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to say that it "Own edits made by anonymous contributors to the site".

Comment: @JeffAtwood, this should be done standard, please... This is not the first site where this issue comes up.

Comment: ah, if I'd known we could do that I would have. (Missed that snippet in pro-tem mod training:-)

Comment: Good idea.  It seems to me that it also owns edits that needed approval, and were modified by the approver, so I suggest adding that case also.

Answer (score 5):

I think Community also takes ownership for edits by anonymous suggestions as well. I saw that proposed edit come through and at that point it was tagged anonymous-user.

Comment: ah, good. But the user page of Community should mention that.

Comment: Yeah- I honestly wouldn't have known if the edit hadn't appeared on my review queue:-) I'll have a look on the main meta page at meta.so when I'm back in print of a computer and post up more info here.